# Django autoredirect to default language not work with Debug=False

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I have app, with next urls.py

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/social/login/cancelled/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', include(cms_urls)),
)
```

also in settings.py I setup:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = "de"
LANGUAGES = [
    ('de', _('German')),
    # ('en', _('English')),
]
```

so, if `DEBUG = True` when I go to `/` url app automatically redirect me to '/de/', but if `DEBUG = False` - app not autoredirect me to `/de`, I just got 404 error

How I can manage it on production with `DEBUG = False`?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup and it works both in debug and prod. My `urls.py` is slightly different:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    ...
    re_path('^$', index, name='root'),
    re_path(r'^', include('cms.urls'))
)
```

`index` is my home view.